# yui3 change iframe head

Tags: javascript, iframe, yui3

I want to inject iframe head by yui3.The sample code works in FF but IE9 shows the error "YUI is not define". I don't know what happens in IE9.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./test-yui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="#" id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
    var SC = 'script';
    YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
        var frame = Y.Node.getDOMNode(Y.one('#frame'));
        o = frame.contentWindow.document;
        o.open().write(
            '<head><' + SC + ' type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.0/build``/yui/yui-min.js"></' + SC + '>'+
            '<' + SC + '>YUI().use(\'tabview\', \'node\', function(Y) {});</' + SC + '>'+
            '</head>'+
            '<body><div class="unit_title" >HELLO WORLD</div></body>');
        o.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write to iframes can be tricky I would suggest looking at the [Frame](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Frame.html) module in YUI some details on using it can be found here http://www.andrewwooldridge.com/blog/2011/04/14/hidden-yui-gem-frame/